# Update table 2 if column in table 1 is not Null

Tags: mysql

Im trying to understand the IF Condition in MySQL.

For my test I have 2 Tables.

Table 1:

```
 + UserId
 + Firstname
 + ResetID (FK)
```

Table 2:

```
 + ResetID (PK) AUTO_INCREMENT
 + code
```

`ResetID` in `Table 1` is `NULL` by Default.

If I add a Code, I want to check if `ResetID` from `Table 1` is `NULL`.

If it's `NULL` I want to `INSERT` a new `row` into `Table 2` with the `code`.
After Insert, `ResetID` in `Table 1` should be the same `ResetID` as in `Table 2`.

If it's `NOT NULL` and containing a `ResetID` which matches the `ResetID` in `Table 2` then only the `code` should be updated.

Im a bit weird about the `IF` Condition in MySQL cause they looks pretty difficult on w3schools.

Comment: You can't do this in a single query. This should be done in a trigger that runs when you insert into table 2.

Comment: What do you mean by "check if ResetID from Table 1 is NULL"? Which row in Table 1 should you check?

Comment: Oh Okay. Because I saw big SQL Queries of IF Conditions ^^.

Comment: A single query can't insert into one table and update another table at the same time. You could also do this in a stored procedure.

Comment: I want to Check `ResetID` because if `ResetID` is `NULL` then I have to create a new row in `Table 2`. If it's `NOT NULL` then the User already have a `ResetID`, so its not needed to create a new one. If the user already have a `ResetID` then just the `Code` should be Updated.

Comment: But which ResetID do you want to check? Which `UserID` should you use?

Comment: I want to check the `ResetID` from `Table 1`.

Comment: But which user's ResetID?

Comment: There's no `UserID` in `Table 2`, so how will it know which row in `Table 1` it should check?

Comment: From the user which want to reset it's database. If User 1 click "reset" then the query should check "if ResetID in table 1 is Null or not" if its not null that means, that the User alread has an ResetID which is in Table 2. If its Null that means, the user has no ResetID and a ResetID in Table 2 should be created and after the ResetID is created it can be insert into the ResetID from Table 1.

Comment: Since there's no `UserID` in the `INSERT` query on Table 2, you need to write a stored procedure. It will take the `UserID` and `code` as parameters. It can then perform the logic you describe with `IF` statements.

Comment: I'm not sure how much more I can help you without writing the code for you. I hope that guidance points you in the right direction.

Comment: Yea. I thought it would be possible with a big IF Condition. But I guess I need to add multiple SQL Queries in my PHP code.

Comment: `IF` can only be used in procedures, not queries.

Comment: These kinds of issues can be symptomatic of flawed design